# Multiple iterations of async/await not working as intended in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written some code below that isolates the issue I am having.

I am trying to send each post sequentially: one after the other. The second request doesn't seem to complete, even if I remove the timeout. (The server responds very quickly anyway).

I've tried different things such as moving async into a higher scope, using promises (which loses the sequential behaviour) to no success.

Why does this happen?

Edit: After replacing the await `got.post(...)` with
`await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))` I see that each sleep occurs in sequence (one after the other) which is what I would like. The last remaining piece of the puzzle is why this doesn't work with got library.

```
const got = require('got')
const FormData = require('form-data')
const fs = require('fs')

var f = new FormData();
f.append('password', 'wrong')
f.append('swupdate.swu', fs.createReadStream('./fake.swu'))

postFormToIPs(
    f
);

async function postFormToIPs(form){
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        console.log(i);
        const { body } = await got.post('http://postman-echo.com/post', {
            body: form,
            timeout: 5000
        });
        console.log(body)
    }
}
```

```
>>> node index.js
0
server response
1
timeout and callstack
```

I would like to see

```
0
server response
1
server response
```

Edit: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/35122
I think the filestream is getting closed after the first request gives a response back. Adding multiple filestreams solves the issue but ideally I will only use one.

Comment: I see your endpoint is `/update`. Any chance you should be using `got.put` instead of post?

Comment: okay I am not sure what do you mean "post request sequentially so that I don't open too many connections. " but if that means you want them to be sent one after the other I can tell you that a for loop of await don't do that , node will go through the for loop without awaiting a thing and will fire all of them in mms and when they resolve you get the result so it's like all of them are firing in the same time ,

Comment: @abney317 Unfortunately, no. The webserver has /update responding to post requests only, but I will keep this convention in mind when developing the server api.

Comment: @ChamsddineBouzaine The behaviour I see shows that each event fires after the other. I have confirmed this behaviour by using the "await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))" one liner after. If I was to move the post request into an (async () => {  })(); closure I would see the parallel behaviour that you describe and I think is more typical, but not what I am looking for.

I may be able to add some timestamps to the console output to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea for a solution, but its good to have an understanding of what is actually going on here and whats causing the problem.

The `FormData` implementation for `NodeJS` does not work the same as it does in the browser. If you look into the implementation of the `form-data` package, you'll see that the `FormData` acts like a readable stream that writes to the http request (in this case,
the `got` post request). Values from `FormData` are written to the request one by one until there are none left. Values are then cleared from `FormData` (you can see this happening under `FormData._streams`). Afterwards, the `FormData` is then considered `released` (defined by an internal property), preventing it from writing to any other request.

You can see all this happening by using the `debugger` or logging the `FormData` object before and after making the first request. You are still able to append other values to the FormData object but you're unable to write these properties to the request object. This is whats causing the second request to hang.

The proper way to go about making these request one after the other would be to create a new FormData instance for every request and appending the same values to it.

As for the file stream, you able to keep this open and have reuse the same stream as long as you assign it to a variable.

```js
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./fake.swu');

async function postFormToIPs(){ 
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){ 
        console.log(i); 
        var f = new FormData(); 
        f.append('password', 'wrong') 
        f.append('swupdate.swu', fileStream) 
        const { body } = await got.post('http://postman-echo.com/post', { 
            body: f,
            timeout: 5000
        }); 
        console.log(body) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight on why this happens. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I currently have. I would improve it by reusing the same file stream but I'm not sure if that's possible.

```
async function postFormToIPs(){ 
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){ 
        console.log(i); 
        var f = new FormData(); 
        f.append('password', 'wrong') 
        f.append('swupdate.swu', fs.createReadStream('./fake.swu')) 
        const { body } = await got.post('http://postman-echo.com/post', { 
            body: f 
        }); 
        console.log(body) 
    } 
}
```